# How to show eigenvalues and singular values are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be Hermitian and positive semi-definite i.e. $x^TAx \ge 0$

Let $K=A^TA=A^2$

$Ax=\lambda x$. Then $Kx=A^2x=\lambda^2 x$

Then, every eigenvector $x$ of $A$ is also eigenvector of $K$ with eigenvalue 
$\lambda^2$.

How can I show the identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive definite matrix can be diagonalized as $A= U D U^H$. Then, $A^H A = A A^H = U D^2 U^H$, so the eigenvalues of $A^H A $ are the squared eigenvalues of $A$. But the eigenvalues of $A^H A$ are the squared singular values of $A$.

So we have eigenvalues squared = singular values squared. Since $A$ is positive definite, eigenvalues are non-negative and singular values are always non-negative so we can take square roots to get eigenvalues = singular values.

Comment: oh thanks! you make it much easier to understand